# Clarify faq on migration

Tags: feature-request, support, migration

I noticed the faq on migration [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work). Under things to consider when migrating it says

> **Avoid migrating answered questions**. The point of migration is to send the question to an on-topic place when it can get answered. If the OP already has an answer, then we've already defeated the purpose of migration and the destination site won't have anything to do with the question. Avoid migrating these questions unless they are of extremely good quality and risk deletion on the current site.

Then I saw this question [Is it worthwhile to migrate questions that already have accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61311/is-it-worthwhile-to-migrate-questions-that-already-have-accepted-answers). The accepted answer says

> Yes, absolutely! Those questions belong to the other site, accepted or not, because that's the place where they will be useful for other users in the future.

These two are confusing me. Can the faq on migration be clarified more about this issue?

Comment: You're overlooking a very important part of that statement. *"Avoid migrating these questions **unless they are of extremely good quality and risk deletion on the current site.**"* If the question and answer aren't of any particularly good quality, just close it as off-topic and move on.

Answer (score 6):

The latter is better for two reasons:

1. The question is moved to where it belongs. From a purely logical perspective, it makes sense to put the question where it's on-topic, even if it already has an answer.
2. A signal is sent to any potential viewers that the question isn't on-topic here, but *is* on-topic elsewhere. It indicates to the reader that the sites have defined topics.

I'm not going to personally edit the community wiki, though, unless the community agrees with the change.

Do remember, though, that the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts are written by *community*-members, and are not official stances on issues. While most of the posts do reflect quorum very well, there is occasionally the sentence or two which does not reflect community consensus. So, while the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) is a very helpful resource, if something seems odd, take it with a grain of salt :]